# Web page localization in php

Tags: php, localization

Suppose I have two url for the same file, say `http://site.com/fr/page.php` and `http://site.com/en/page.php`.

In the end it is the exact same file that is executed, but the first url ouputs text in french, the second in english.

Using asp.net I would achieve that by setting the thread's `Culture` and `UICulture` property, then use two resx resources files to get the strings to display based on that culture.

How can I achieve something similar with php?

I have seen gettext, but as I understand it I cannot use it with different language on a per request basis. I'm not sure if `setlocale` and `putenv` affects *all* the request or just the current one.

I know that some frameworks may provide that functionality (zend_translate?), but I don't want to use it. This project is mainly for me to learn, and I want it the most independant as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setlocale` and `putenv` affects just the current one. You can save your culture into session.